# Why was this question deleted, not just closed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/99197/input-data-source-to-a-baisc-glass-flight-display-system

I had just clicked the edit button to try to fix the grammar and spelling in this question, but the page turned gray and a notice that the question had been deleted appeared. Why was it deleted, instead of closing it and leaving the possibility of improving it?

Comment: It was a poorly written, poorly reasoned question that was down-voted & had attracted an AI / spam answer. If you think you can turn it into a quality question, I can un-delete it, but what was being asked seemed to make no sense as written. Just fixing the grammar won't improve the underlying quality issue.

Comment: @RalphJ I understood it as asking whether the data input to a glass cockpit is digital or analog. Of course, the data has to be analog at some point (air pressure, for example, can't be directly measured digitally), and it has to be digital at some point (otherwise the computer couldn't handle it), so I would probably have changed it to ask at what point the data is converted from analog to digital.

Comment: That understanding is much better than what was expressed in the other question. If you want to ask that, I'd recommend starting a new thread, asking your question, and not inheriting the DV that the other one had.

Comment: @RalphJ thank you! I posted https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/99208/at-what-point-is-the-input-data-to-glass-cockpit-pfds-converted-to-digital .

Comment: Nice question, clearly stated, useful to others - +1'd. What you posted is likely to get a couple of good answers, especially not starting off with the -2 score. Nice job!

Comment: And... 10 hours later, your question has two really excellent answers! (One of those, by a user who VTC'd  the original question.)